# Why is my vba code returning back the placeholder text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and word macros so please bear with me.
I've created a simple form and now I just want to do some validation on a button, before emailing it.

I've got some code here.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim errors As String

   errors = ""

   Dim strText As String
   strText = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MyField")(1).Range.Text

   errors = strText //debugging line - remove if required

   If strText = "" Then
        If errors = "" Then
            errors = "MyField Blank"
        Else
            errors = errors & vbNewLine & "Practise Name Blank"
        End If

   End If



   If errors = "" Then
        Options.SendMailAttach = True
        ActiveDocument.SendMail
   Else
        MsgBox "Please Correct Then Following Errors" & vbNewLine & errors
   End If

End Sub
```

Which is attached to a button, but the strText is returning back the placeholder text. How do you stop this from happening?

I'm using the new version of the word forms controls.

Comment: Off topic, there is no need for `errors = ""`. In VBA `String` type variables are declared as a null string as default.

Comment: @Dean I don't understand your comment. Why does your observation make this off-topic? The question is about how to work around a content control's placeholder text...

Comment: Richard, I can appreciate why you want to modify the code in the answer, but I feel it should match the code in the question. Otherwise, it could confuse people. If it's important to you, it might be better to comment out those two lines (writing in the correct `If` line) with a comment that they were for debugging purposes?

Comment: @CindyMeister hi the first line errors = strText is the debugging and I can make that as 'debugging' the ' Or strText = ph' in the first if - is a slight error. As it should only go in there if errors is blank and you don't need a break/new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you write, my approach to this would be to check the placeholder text and compare the content control's content with that. If they're the same, it's as if the content control had no content.

Note that I'm unsure what is intended with the last `IF`-block since, given the preceding code, `errors` cannot be an empty (zero-length) string - it would always contain something, based on the `If`-block preceding. But perhaps this is due to testing the problem with the placeholders...

```
  Dim errors As String, ph As String
  Dim cc As Word.ContentControl

   errors = ""

   Dim strText As String
   Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("MyField")(1)
   ph = cc.PlaceholderText
   strText = cc.Range.Text

   errors = strText

   If strText = "" Or strText = ph Then
        If errors = "" Or strText = ph Then
            errors = "MyField Blank"
        Else
            errors = errors & vbNewLine & "Practise Name Blank"
        End If

   End If

   If errors = "" Then
        Options.SendMailAttach = True
        ActiveDocument.SendMail
   Else
        MsgBox "Please Correct Then Following Errors" & vbNewLine & errors
   End If
```

Comment: Thanks yeah it was just testing what was in the field and seemed like the simplest way. Thanks for your help.
Richard